# why the new window has delayed reaction

Tags: tidesdk

Firstly, when we create a new window for web address by using TIDESDK, it always has delayed reaction in input form input, but when we open a new web address by using chrome browser, it has no delayed reaction, why it happens like that ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to 2 year old webkit within TideSDK.

Comment: I have found the reason, but thank you all the same! CSS compatibility problems!

Comment: Mital's answer is the correct one, the age of the WebKit implies that you will need to verify that your CSS will work and parse correctly. This is a current inconvenience at the moment and may mean temporary adjustments. This is something we are addressing and will have news on about as soon as we are ready.